# Spring MongoTemplate Pageable query not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I"m trying to execute a mongo query with pagination in a Spring boot application. I have 4 records in my table. And I'm trying to get the last 2 records by filter with Page filter request.

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page/2, pageSize);
Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass.class)
```

The query shown in debug statements.

```
{
"find": "JourneyActionConfiguration",
"filter": {
    "$and": [{
        "organizationId": "1eb6abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdcaeabcd"
    }, {
        "workspaceId": "63cede492d4bb527103deabf"
    }, {
        "isActive": true
    }]
},
"skip": 2,
"limit": 2,
"$db": "Journey",
"lsid": {
    "id": {
        "$binary": {
            "base64": "pT34Cz0AQj6mQHAWM6MxjA==",
            "subType": "04"
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I use the Skip, Limit with 2 in MongoDB Compass, it works as expected. But, through the code using PageRequest.of, it doesn't work. Can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: What are the values of page and pageSize you're passng to PageRequest.of() ?

Comment: What isn't working about it? Is it throwing an error, returning incorrect results, something else? Also, where is the sort?

Comment: Do all 4 records satisfy the filters on the `organizationId`, `workspaceId` and `isActive` fields?

Comment: I'm using Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page/2, pageSize);
All the records satisfy the criteria.